# Generar una semana que empieze por el dia lunes en donde se incluya mi fecha (PHP)

Tags: php

Quisiera obtener los dias de una semana empezando desde el lunes basado en la fecha que yo le indique. por ejemplo basado en el dia 16-05-2023, tomando en cuenta que lunes cae 1,8,15,22 y 29
si yo le indico la fecha `16-05-2023` me genere:

```
15-16-17-18-19-20-21
```

ya que la semana a la que pertenece el 16-05 empieza desde el dia lunes.
otro ejemplo seria: el dia 31-05-2023 me generaria:

```
29-30-31-1-2-3-4
```

en donde se empezó por el dia 29 ya que el 29 cae lunes y se completaron los dias con los dias del mes siguiente.

**Contexto:** lo que deseo es generar las semanas de un calendario para poder estructurar una agenda que me muestre las citas de una semana del mes.

esto intenté:

```
<?php
function generarSemana($fecha) {
    $diaSemana = date('N', strtotime($fecha));
    $fechaInicio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha . ' -' . ($diaSemana - 1) . ' days'));

    $diasSemana = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $dia = date('d', strtotime($fechaInicio . ' +' . $i . ' days'));
        $diasSemana[] = $dia;
    }

    return $diasSemana;
}

$fecha = '09-05-2023';
$fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $fecha))); // Formatear fecha

$diasSemana = generarSemana($fecha);

foreach ($diasSemana as $dia) {
    echo $dia . ' - ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Iba a escribir una respuesta, pero no es necesaria por la excelente que ha aportado A. Cedano. Aunque si te diré en qué falla el código y está en la conversión de la fecha. PHP la está tomándola como `m/d/Y` porque cambias los `'-'` por `'/'`. Si eliminas el `str_replace`, el código funciona relativamente bien. Finalmente para convertir el array en texto, no es necesario el `for`, puedes usar `echo implode(' - ', $diasSemana);`

Answer (score 1):

Esto es relativamente fácil con la ayuda de las clases:

- [`DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)
- [`DatePeriod()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php)
- [`DateInterval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php)

Partiendo de una fecha dada (`$givenDate`), verificaremos primero si tal fecha no es lunes, en cuyo caso, supongo, no habría que mover al lunes anterior (si me equivoco sólo tienes que quitar el `if`). Esa fecha marcará en cualquier caso el inicio del período.

Luego crearemos una copia de esa fecha dada y la modificaremos en una semana, para obtener la fecha de fin (`$endDate`).

Finalmente, creamos un `DatePeriod` que contendrá objetos `DateTime` comprendidos entre la fecha dada y la fecha final y los mostramos en un bucle. Ten en cuenta que cada fecha en el período es un verdadero objeto `DateTime`, con todas las posibilidades que ello ofrece, como mostrarlo en el formato que mejor te convenga, etc.

Otra ventaja de usar las clases temporales de PHP es que puedes implementar manejo de errores, en caso de fechas inválidas por ejemplo.

Podemos meter todo en una función:

```
function generateWeekFromMonday($dateString){
    try {
            $givenDate = new DateTime($dateString);
            
            /*
                Verificas si la fecha dada no es lunes
                para moverla al próximo lunes
                Si ya es lunes no haría falta modificarla, pues
                ¡ya es lunes!
            */
            if ($givenDate->format('N') != 1) {
                $givenDate->modify('last monday');
            }
            /*
                Creamos una copia de la fecha dada
                y luego le añadimos el período de una semana: P1W
                para crear el intervalo
            */
            $endDate = clone $givenDate;
            $endDate->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));
            /*
                Creamos el período entre la fecha dada
                y la fecha final, indicando un intervalo de un día: P1D
                e imprimimos cada fecha de ese período en el foreach
                Nótese que hay un perído de objetos DateTime ahí y que
                si quieres otro formato distinto de 'd' también lo puedes obtener
            */
            $datePeriod= new DatePeriod($givenDate,new DateInterval('P1D'),$endDate);
            foreach($datePeriod as $theDate){
                echo $theDate->format("d"),PHP_EOL;
            }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

Y para probarla, varios casos de uso:

```
generateWeekFromMonday('2023-05-16');
echo PHP_EOL;

generateWeekFromMonday('2023-05-31');
echo PHP_EOL;

#Caso de una fecha que es lunes
generateWeekFromMonday('2023-05-22');
echo PHP_EOL;

#Caso de una fecha errónea
generateWeekFromMonday('2023-99999-22');
```

**Salida:**

```
15
16
17
18
19
20
21

29
30
31
01
02
03
04

22
23
24
25
26
27
28

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2023-99999-22) at position 6 (9): Double date specification
```

---

Si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios. **Soy humano, no soy una IA.**